# Codeigniter 4.1.1 shows undefined variable even after using isset function

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I have multiple views that are used in the main view called Body. I didn't declared $sub_page and it showed `undefined variable`. I tried declaring it as `null` but still, the if block is executed.

Error
[image: Shows undefined variable error]

Function

```
public function index()
    {
        $Main = model('App\Models\mainModel');
        $fields = ["id","product_name","product_uid","product_price","instock"];
        $data = [
            'site' => "Billing",
            'page' => "Products",
            'table' => "products",
            'data' => $Main->get_data("products",$fields),
            'is_verify' => false,
            'is_action' => true,
            'fields' => $fields
        ];
        return view('Body',$data);
    }
```

BreadCrumb View

```
<div class="content-header">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="mr-auto">
            <h3 class="page-title"><?=$page?></h3>
            <div class="d-inline-block align-items-center">
                <nav>
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?=base_url()?>"><i class="mdi mdi-home-outline"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item" aria-current="page"><?=$page?></li>
                        <?if(isset($sub_page)):?>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><?=$sub_page?></li>
                        <?endif;?>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Body View

```
   <div class="wrapper">
        <?=view("Header")?>
        <?=view("Navigation")?>
        <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-full">
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
                <?=view("Breadcrumb")?>
                <section class="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?if(isset($views)):?>
                        <?foreach ($views as $view):?>
                        <?=view($view)?>
                        <?endforeach;?>
                        <?endif;?>
                        <?if(isset($table)):?>
                        <?=view("Datatable")?>
                        <?endif;?>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?=view("Footer")?>
    </div>
```

Why this error is showing, How to solve it

Comment: Try `var_dump($sub_page)` your variable, and see if it's not null. Handle it with respect to it.

Comment: I just found page source is showing PHP tags `<??>`, but other PHP files working fine it shows only in this project folder

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `short_open_tag` after adding `php_flag short_open_tag on` in .htaccess file solved my problem. php.ini has `short_open_tag=On` but it still showed error but adding above tag in .htaccess solved the problem